# ATG 11 REST call with parameters

Tags: java, rest, atg

I need to call method using ATG 11 REST API.

```
public String getString(String str) {
     return str;
}
```

I created actor properties configuration like this:

```
$class=atg.service.actor.ActorChainService
definitionFile=/path/to/service/accountServiceActor.xml
```

And that my accountServiceActor.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actor-template default-chain-id="cartService"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.atg.com/xsds/actorChain_1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <actor-chain id="getString" transaction="TX_SUPPORTS">
        <component id="getString" name="/path/to/service/AccountService"
                   method="getString" method-return-var="str">
            <input name="str" value="${param.str}" />
            <output id="str" name="str" value="${str}" />
        </component>
    </actor-chain>
</actor-template>
```

Also I updated **AccessControlServlet.properties** and **ActorChainRestRegistry.properties**

So my rest call is here:

```
curl -L -v -b customer_cookies.txt -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "str" : "value" }' http://localhost:7003/path/to/service/AccountServiceActor/getString
```

And i am getting this error:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f8eb9803000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f8eb9803000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 7003 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 7003 (#0)
> POST /path/to/service/AccountServiceActor/getString HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:7003
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: DYN_USER_CONFIRM=f0f599f9f11aa5571d7055c2b4c7c9d5; DYN_USER_ID=240004; JSESSIONID=6iUR5qvjjBHPhSNq6zMh_B6dn18lwhKFWvPbOZxTekUIhsFPqf3r!-1528908093
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 20
>
* upload completely sent off: 20 out of 20 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Connection: close
< Date: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 11:19:21 GMT
< Content-Length: 265
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-ATG-Version: version=QVRHUGxhdGZvcm0vMTEuMA==
* Replaced cookie JSESSIONID="fcMSCqdKrO-PvMyLalmJHSnuHBa0VEBaJscD01nZYZDOXCXs6Q3j!-1528908093" for domain localhost, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=fcMSCqdKrO-PvMyLalmJHSnuHBa0VEBaJscD01nZYZDOXCXs6Q3j!-1528908093; path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
<
CONTAINER:atg.service.actor.ActorException: There was an error while trying to find a method.&#59; SOURCE:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: path.to.service.impl.AccountService.getString&#40;null&#41;
```

What i am doing wrong? Help me to make my configuration correct.

Comment: Are you able to access any web service on your server? Also, are you using weblogic?

Comment: Yes, i m using weblogic. Problem is not in the environment, problem is in rest component configuration.

Comment: Did you configure it through the /dyn/admin web service configuration?

Comment: I can create method without parameters and call it through REST. But when I add parameter in method, i get error when i m calling method. I think, error in actor configuration, and dyn/admin will not help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input name="str" class-name="java.lang.String" value="${param.str}" />
```

Please add class-name attribute in your input parameter:Snippet:

Answer (score 0):

1-Enclose http://localhost:7003/path/to/service/AccountServiceActor/getString in double qoutes,i.e
"http://localhost:7003/path/to/service/AccountServiceActor/getString".

2-Also replace '{ "str" : "value" }' with "{ "str" : "value" }"

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure of the following points :

1. Actor property file name and Actor xml file name should be the same 
   i.e. in your case accountServiceActor.xml and AccountServiceActor.properties
2. Use the URL with /rest/model/ i.e. in your case    http://localhost:7003/rest/model/path/to/service/AccountServiceActor/getString
3. Make sure that in the ActorChainRestRegistry.propeties the URL is correctly registered i.e. in your case registeredUrls+=/path/to/service/accountServiceActor/getString
4. Make sure that the method getString() exist in the component /path/to/service/AccountService :)

Comment: Actor property file name and Actor xml file name should be the same - is wrong. in Actor property we just give the actor xml name, it can be anything. ATG only suggests they should be in same folder nothing else.